How can I change rectangular recessed light bulbs?
I just bought a condo and one of the three lights in the kitchen is burned out. I can't for the life of me figure out how to remove the light bulb. It doesn't twist left or right; I've tried pushing it up and twisting it both ways and that doesn't work. I've even tried to pull it straight out but that doesn't work. I tried all of these on all three bulbs (even the two good ones) and nothing.
I can't even find these bulbs on Google. Searching for combinations of the following term won't show any images: rectangular, square, LED, CFL, recessed, canister, ceiling, light, bulb
Here are two photos I took of the lights. The openings are about 3 inches. Any idea what these are and how I can change them out?



What happens if you pull downward on the white flange?

Can you hold your phone up so the camera lens is looking in the gap around the bulb, and take a flash picture of what's behind it?

These might be held by a V-shaped spring. As @isherwood states, try pulling down gently on the ring, or, if that does not move, on the edge of the reflector. See this picture for what the back might look like: https://www.emergencylights.net/products/halco-99741-810-lumens-9-watt-2700-kelvin-5-6-in-retrofit-led-downlight-fixture-75-watt-incandescent-equal-stepped-baffle-trim-dimmable-90-cri-120-volt

Have you tried to unscrew one of the working bulbs?  There's a chance this one may simply be screwed in too tight (although if this one was overtightened, there's probably a good chance the others are too).

Yeah, I've tried also with the other two lights. I can't unscrew any of them; I can't pull them straight down; and I've tried a push and twist (like with a prescription pill bottle). None of them budges at all.

I started to pull down on the collar the other day but chickened out. I'll give it another shot when I go over to the unit tomorrow. My brother thinks it might be an all-in-one canister light. He says his electrician friend swears by them.
